# How to get all attachments list in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm working with custom module which should show latest (defined count) added attachments.
I see this piece of code in **class/Attachment.php**

```
public static function getAttachments($id_lang, $id_product, $include = true)
{
    return Db::getInstance()->executeS('
        SELECT *
        FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'attachment a
        LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'attachment_lang al
            ON (a.id_attachment = al.id_attachment AND al.id_lang = '.(int)$id_lang.')
        WHERE a.id_attachment '.($include ? 'IN' : 'NOT IN').' (
            SELECT pa.id_attachment
            FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attachment pa
            WHERE id_product = '.(int)$id_product.'
        )'
    );
}
```

So far i know i dont need this $include check so i need to make custom static function like getAllattachments or new class? Any ideas much appreciated.

In module i have this

```
public function hookLeftColumn($params)
{
    if (!$this->isCached('blockattachment.tpl', $this->getCacheId()))
    {
        $attachments = Attachment::getAttachments();
        foreach ($attachments as &$attachment)
        {
            $attachment['image'] = $this->context->language->iso_code.'-default';
            if (file_exists(_PS_MANU_IMG_DIR_.$attachment['id_manufacturer'].'-'.ImageType::getFormatedName('medium').'.jpg'))
                $attachment['image'] = $attachment['id_manufacturer'];
        }

        $this->smarty->assign(array(
            'attachments' => $attachments,
            'text_list' => Configuration::get('ATTACHMENT_DISPLAY_TEXT'),
            'text_list_nb' => Configuration::get('ATTACHMENT_DISPLAY_TEXT_NB'),
            'form_list' => Configuration::get('ATTACHMENT_DISPLAY_FORM'),
            'display_link_manufacturer' => Configuration::get('PS_DISPLAY_SUPPLIERS'),
        ));
    }
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'blockattachment.tpl', $this->getCacheId());
}
```

and in tpl this one

```
{if $attachments}
        {if $text_list}
            <ul class="bullet">
                {foreach from=$attachments item=attachment name=attachment_list}
                    {if $smarty.foreach.attachment_list.iteration <= $text_list_nb}
                    <li><a href="{$link->getAttachmentLink($attachment.id_attachment, $attachment.link_rewrite)|escape:'html'}" title="{l s='More about %s' sprintf=[$attachment.name] mod='blockattachment'}">{$attachment.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</a></li>
                    {/if}
                {/foreach}
            </ul>
        {/if}
    {else}
        <p>{l s='No new attachments' mod='blockattachment'}</p>
    {/if}
```

This all from blockmanufacturer module which was duplicated with changed GetManufacturer function.

Comment: how many attachments of the latest attachments do you want? and only attachments in the user language or all languages?

Comment: hi! in tpl foreach loop there is a limit set by variable from module config (look exact block manufacuter) {if $smarty.foreach.attachment_list.iteration <= $text_list_nb}. From all languages should be fine. thanks mate for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on language, but try this:

```
public static function getLatestAttachments($id_lang, $n = 5)
{
    return Db::getInstance()->executeS('
        SELECT DISTINCT (a.`id_attachment`), a.`file`,  a.`file_name`, a.`file_size`, al.`name`
        FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'attachment a
        LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'attachment_lang al
            ON (a.id_attachment = al.id_attachment AND al.id_lang = '.(int)$id_lang.')
        ORDER BY a.`id_attachment` DESC'.
        ($n > 0 ? ' LIMIT '.$n : '')
    );
}
```

Then in your module you don't need to get all attachments:

```
public function hookLeftColumn($params)
{
    if (!$this->isCached('blockattachment.tpl', $this->getCacheId()))
    {
        $attachments = Attachment::getLatestAttachments($this->context->language->id, Configuration::get('ATTACHMENT_DISPLAY_TEXT_NB'));
        foreach ($attachments as &$attachment)
        {
            $attachment['image'] = $this->context->language->iso_code.'-default';
            if (file_exists(_PS_MANU_IMG_DIR_.$attachment['id_manufacturer'].'-'.ImageType::getFormatedName('medium').'.jpg'))
                $attachment['image'] = $attachment['id_manufacturer'];
        }

        $this->smarty->assign(array(
            'attachments' => $attachments,
            'text_list' => Configuration::get('ATTACHMENT_DISPLAY_TEXT'),
            'form_list' => Configuration::get('ATTACHMENT_DISPLAY_FORM'),
            'display_link_manufacturer' => Configuration::get('PS_DISPLAY_SUPPLIERS'),
        ));
    }
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'blockattachment.tpl', $this->getCacheId());
}
```

And your tpl:

```
{if $attachments}
        {if $text_list}
            <ul class="bullet">
                {foreach from=$attachments item=attachment name=attachment_list}
                    <li><a href="{$link->getAttachmentLink($attachment.id_attachment, $attachment.name)|escape:'html'}" title="{l s='More about %s' sprintf=[$attachment.name] mod='blockattachment'}">{$attachment.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</a></li>
                {/foreach}
            </ul>
        {/if}
    {else}
        <p>{l s='No new attachments' mod='blockattachment'}</p>
    {/if}
```

Btw, i don't think there is the link_rewrite in attachments.

Comment: Thanks but got Error 500. public static function getLatestAttachments($id_lang, $n = 5) goes to Attachment.php class. Rest on module php and tpl. I think is something wrong with query.

Comment: I haven't tested. I don't have any attchments. Can you turn debug mode on? In your condif/defines.inc.php change define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false); to define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true); and post the error? Also you should put the function inside the attachments override. Create the file /override/classes/Attachment.php with class Attachment extends AttachmentCore then paste the function. Then delete/rename the file cache/class_index.php.

Comment: The baddest thing is that Dev Mode dont work and i cant see where is the problem :( I can send You few bucks on PP if You will check the module and show me some demo. Thanks!!! :)

Comment: Some tweaks and almost done! ($n > 0 ? ' LIMIT '.$n : ''); should be ($n > 0 ? ' LIMIT '.$n : '') without end ";" . So far so good. Now the main problem is to get attachment link because getAttachmentLink function not exist anywhere